# itunes software upgrade not syncing music

Tags: itunes, ios, data-synchronization

I made the mistake of upgrading itunes software and when I plugged in my iphone 4 it erased all of my music. I have since tried to resync but it is stuck on the 2nd song copy and I cant seem to figure out why? All of my songs are still on my computer and on a separate hard drive but I dont understand why it wont sync?

Answer (score 1):

This clearly isn't how an iTunes upgrade is supposed to go. There are quite different strategies for fixing sync issues depending on whether you have a Mac or a PC, so the best I can offer is to work from the script and perhaps ask another question if you have a problem with a specific step.

- [iOS: Syncing with iTunes (KB HT1386)](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1386)

Also, the problem could be entirely on the iTunes end - so it's a bit of a game to eliminate things one by one. You might take your phone to another computer (now that it's presumably erased) and get a good iCloud backup and test syncing there. This will let you focus on either the iPhone or the computer.